# What does "zoozi" or "zoozie" mean?

Tags: slang

I've heard a phrase in London, it sounded like "It's a big zoozi" or something like that. I wonder what this could mean?

Comment: @sumelic, it was in an office in a talk between 2 colleagues.

Comment: Why don't you ask them?  In American slang in the 1920s it meant a very pretty girl; in modern slang it apparently means lint (see Urban Dictionary). If neither of these make sense, you and we need more context. What were the colleagues discussing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I just misheard it.

> Doozy - something that is unusually good, bad, big, severe, etc.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doozy